# How to use kexec reboot to new kernel from diskless thinclient

Tags: 14.04, boot, 18.04, reboot

I've a diskless workstation which boot #ubuntu on LAN. 
However, the version 14.04 on tftp server is becoming outdated.

I am seeking for a solution that I should able to "reboot" the diskless machines into a fresh 18.04 installation by `kexec` on another NFS server.

- p.s. I have no control on neither DHCP/tftp server it was booted from.
  But I have root access on the workstation itself and another NFS server.
- p.p.s. It can, but I don't want to plug any USB or disk.
- p.p.p. It run BIOS, not UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Found [pxe-kexec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/pxe-kexec.8.html) which doing very similar to what I am looking for.

`pxe-kexec` use tftp/ftp to download image from PXE server and `kexec` to reboot.

In order to achieve the reboot, you need to

- setup a tftp server for hosting kernel image
- setup a NFS server for hosting post-boot system disk.
- run `pxe-kexec [my-server-ip]`